# What is the node-way to talk about require, import, and packages?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two files in my javascript project:

app.js

```
require('sugar')
var Notification = require('./notification');

let createdOn = 'now'
let notifyOn = 'in 2 days'
let someNotification = new Notification('go somewhere', Date.create(createdOn), Date.create(notifyOn))
someNotification.print()
```

notification.js

```
function Notification(content, createdOn, notifyOn) {
  this.content = content
  this.createdOn = createdOn
  this.notifyOn = notifyOn
}

Notification.prototype.print = function() {
  console.log('content', this.content)
  console.log('createdOn', this.createdOn)
  console.log('notifyOn', this.notifyOn)
}

module.exports = Notification
```

in `notification.js` I think I'm "writing my own module" that "exports a constructor" to whatever requires it. Then in `app.js` I "import my the Notification module" which is in the same working directory as `app.js`. I also "import the Sugar package" so I can convert natural language into a DateTime see [Sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/dates) for details about that.

Next I'm "creating an instance of Notification" and calling one of it's "instance methods".

I'm wondering: what is the node-way for saying everything above, especially the parts in quotes? Specifically I'm confused about how to speak precisely about a constructor, and prototype functions, and what the difference is between these two lines:

```
require('sugar')
var Notification = require('./notification');
```

I'm looking for an answer that, using node idioms, explains to me what I did in my project.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no documented, standard node idiom-speak.  Your explanation is pretty much what you are doing in terms that any node developer would understand.  Here's the shortest node-phrasing I can think of:

> require('sugar')

load the sugar module

> var Notification = require('./notification');

load the notification module from the current module's directory and assign the exports to a variable named `Notification`

> notification.js

A module that exports a constructor function for creating `Notification` objects.

---

> what the difference is between these two lines:

```
require('sugar')
var Notification = require('./notification');
```

The sugar module can be used without assigning its exports to any variable because the main thing it does is add methods to the existing `Date` and `Number` prototype (commonly referred to as "extending an existing object") and you use many of its features by accessing methods like `Date.create()` that it added.

So, its functionality is added to objects that already exist and that's how you use its functionality.  This is not particularly common - I'm not aware of any specific name for a module that loads this way.

> Next I'm "creating an instance of Notification" and calling one of
>   its "instance methods".

That is already a node-way to say it.